# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class “Tutor\Models\CourseModel” not found

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

After install Tutor LMS plugin this error occurred . My PHP version is 8.0.30 and TutorLMS Version: 2.4.0

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class “Tutor\Models\CourseModel” not found in /var/www/h/wp-content/plugins/tutor/classes/Course.php:142 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/h/wp-content/plugins/tutor/classes/Tutor.php(494): TUTOR\Course->__construct() #1 /var/www/h/wp-content/plugins/tutor/classes/Tutor.php(437): TUTOR\Tutor->__construct() #2 /var/www/h/wp-content/plugins/tutor/tutor.php(158): TUTOR\Tutor::instance() #3 /var/www/h/wp-content/plugins/tutor/tutor.php(178): tutor_lms() #4 /var/www/h/wp-settings.php(473): include_once(‘…’) #5 /var/www/h/wp-config.php(115): require_once(‘…’) #6 /var/www/h/wp-load.php(50): require_once(‘…’) #7 /var/www/h/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once(‘…’) #8 /var/www/h/index.php(17): require(‘…’) #9 {main} thrown in /var/www/h/wp-content/plugins/tutor/classes/Course.php on line 142

Notice: Function is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /var/www/h/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6031

Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /var/www/h/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6031

There has been a critical error on this website.

I have tried several approaches for solving this but couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

tutor lms needs to update their code to make it php8 compatible ... it's a joke it isn't already.